# When a gem fails, where do I find the mkmf.log file?

Tags: rubygems

> Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
>
> ** extconf.rb failed **
>
> Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the
> mkmf.log file for more details.

Where do I find the mkmf.log file?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

The mkmf.log file can be found under the gem's installation directory.

**rvm**

If you are using RVM, then look for a directory similar to

> ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/some-cool-gem-name/ext/mkmf.log

You can list all the mkmf.log files available with this command:

```
find ~/.rvm -name mkmf.log
```

**rbenv**

```
find ~/.rbenv -name mkmf.log
```

Comment: ..or to avoid changing directory or grep-ing needlessly, use `find ~/.rvm -name mkmf.log` instead. It'll run much faster too ;)

Comment: Adding to givanse's answer: find /var/lib -name mkmf.log To find the `mkmf.log` file.

Comment: On OSX 10.10.5 I'm getting `illegal option` when using `-name` flag. Is that a Linux thing?

Comment: @sixty4bit are you by any change trying this: `find  -name mkmf.log`. the first parameter of find needs to be the start directory, like `find . -name mkmf.log` for instance

Comment: @morksinaanab it's been a while but I think that must've been it

Comment: Nope, the log isn't there. What can I do when the install fails and yet the log file isn't where it supposedly should be nor anywhere on the entire disk?

Answer (score 3):

*Windows solution*

As @givanse said, the mkmf logs are in the gem installation directory. Because that can be complicated, you should just search for the mkmf file. You can do that in Windows explorer or in PowerShell

```
cd C:\Dev\Ruby22 # Change to reflect your Ruby install dir
Get-ChildItem mkmf* -Recurse
```

Answer (score 1):

```
find $GEM_HOME -name mkmf.log
```

or

```
$GEM_HOME/extensions/$arch/$ruby_version-static/$gem_name-$gem_version/mkmf.log
```

`chruby`, `ruby-2.6.3`:

```
GEM_HOME: /home/yuri/.gem/ruby/2.6.3
arch: x86_64-linux
ruby_version: 2.6.0
gem_name: openssl
gem_version: 2.0.0

/home/yuri/.gem/ruby/2.6.3/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.6.0-static/openssl-2.0.0/mkmf.log
```

`rvm`, `ruby-2.6.3`:

```
GEM_HOME: /home/yuri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3
arch: x86_64-linux
ruby_version: 2.6.0
gem_name: nokogiri
gem_version: 1.10.3

/home/yuri/.gem/ruby/2.6.3/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.6.0-static/nokogiri-1.10.3/mkmf.log
```