# Ruby on rails gem install rmagick -v '2-13-2'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rmagick

I am facing issue regarding rmagick when i run the command bundle install its gives some error:

Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rmagick:

```
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/home/varun/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20150716-24273-1aef63p.rb extconf.rb
```

checking for gcc... yes
checking for Magick-config... yes
checking for outdated ImageMagick version (<= 6.4.9)... no
checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
Can't install RMagick 2.15.2. Can't find the ImageMagick library or one of the dependent libraries. Check the mkmf.log file for more detailed information.

*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
--without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/home/varun/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /home/varun/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rmagick-2.15.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/varun/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.1.0/rmagick-2.15.2/gem_make.out

when i run gem install rmagick -v '2.13.2' command again find the same error. Please help me...

Comment: ` Check the mkmf.log file for more details.`  What does that say?

Comment: mayby duplicate with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3704919/installing-rmagick-on-ubuntu

Comment: for the log file location look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20379274/when-a-gem-fails-where-do-i-find-the-mkmf-log-file

Comment: I have done all this but no success